# Convert XML to JSON Array when only one object is available using Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, xml, org.json

While converting **XML to JSON** using below Java code (using org.JSON API), I'm not getting JSON Array if only single object is available.

Note - In case multiple objects are available, I'm getting Array as expected.

Java Code:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class Convert {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
        "<School >" +
        "<Class>II-B</Class>" +
        "</School>";

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);

        String json = jsonObj.toString(4);

        System.out.println(json);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}

}
```

Sample XML:

```
<School>
<Class>II-B</Class>
</School>
```

Response JSON:

```
{"School": { "Class": "II-B" }}
```

Instead of Object, I need Array as below -

Expected JSON:

```
{ "School": {"Class": ["II-B"] }}
```

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Hi @AhmetOZKESEK - Shared my code in my Question itself.

Comment: Underscore-java library can convert xml to json. U.xmlToJson(xml) method will help.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't, because there's no way the converter can know the semantics of the XML (that is, that there might be more than one class, but in this case there only happens to be one).

I'm afraid my experience is that generic converters between XML and JSON are pretty well useless. To produce usable output, you always need to do some pre-processing or post-processing that takes account of the semantics of the data model.

That's why XSLT 3.0 doesn't attempt a generic conversion, rather it gives you the tools to implement your own custom conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Declarative Stream Mapping (DSM)](https://mfatihercik.github.io/dsm) stream parsing library. It can process both JSON and XML. First of all, you have to define your mapping in yaml or json format.

Here is the example mapping for your sample XML:

```
result:
  path: /
  type: object
  fields:
    School:
      type: object
      fields:         
        Class: 
          type: array
```

Working example is in below link.

https://repl.it/@MehmetFatihFat3/DSMConvertXMLtoJSONArrayOneElement